# Latex - extract substring/ignore characters

Tags: latex, parsing, token, tex, if-statement

I have the following problem. I have defined a macro, `\func` as follows

```
\newcommand{\func}[1]{% do something with #1  
X #1 Y
}
```

I now want to define another macro

```
\newcommand{\MyFunc}[1]{  
% parse #1 and if it contains "\func{....}", ignore all except this part
% otherwise ignore #1 
}
```

Can someone tell me how to implement `\MyFunc`?

Here is what should happen:

```
\MyFunc{123abcdefg}              % should print nothing
\MyFunc{123\func{abcd}efg}       % should print X abcd Y
```

I can only change the code of `\MyFunc`. `\func` should remain as it is.

Comment: Exactly why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I have a caption in algorithms that is defined as 
    caption{blah blah \func{algorithm_name} blah blah}

When I create the ToC, I want to extract just the algorithm_name (along with the formatting due to \func and ignore the rest.

Comment: Try `\caption[\func{algorithm_name}]{blah blah \func{algorithm_name} blah blah}`.

Comment: no that is too inconveinent. The problem is that the document is already written with thousands of captions. I can call another routine when \caption is called (in the above example, \MyFunc) but I cannot rewrite the actual caption for each algorithm.

Comment: the reason I cannot edit the actual document is because I don't have editing privilages for some sections of the document.

I can edit the root file, where `MyFunc` or `func` is defined

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This can be done with standard LaTeX programming. Something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\func[1]{X #1 Y}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\MyFunc[1]{%
  \in@{\func}{#1}%
  \ifin@
    \ignore@all@but@func#1\@nil
  \fi
}
\def\ignore@all@but@func#1\func#2#3\@nil{\func{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
[\MyFunc{123abcdefg}]              % should print nothing
[\MyFunc{123\func{abcd}efg}]       % should print X abcd Y
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tested & worked here.  There are other ways to get the result, but this should be the simplest.

Comment: thanks!! thats exactly what I was looking for :)
Is there any good resource for learning (La)TeX programming?

Comment: I should mention that I had to change `\newcommand` in your code to `\DeclareRobustCommand`, and then everything worked flawlessly!

(this is related to the actual document of course, not the toy example above)

Comment: @amit: no, there's not really any good place to learn all this stuff. I recommend just reading package sources and the LaTeX2e source (`texdoc source2e`), and asking lots of questions :)

Comment: Something missing: the code needs a `\makeatother` after the newcommand is finished.  It works as is for this example, but will have strange effects for typical latex.

Comment: Fwiw, i'm not aware of any troubles with a missing \makeatother, but you're right. It's a bad habit of mine to omit it.